# WPF Container event when all children have lost focus

Tags: xaml, focus, panel

As an example, suppose I have:

```
<StackPanel>
   <TextBlock />
   <TextBox />
   <TextBox />
</StackPanel>
```

I want to handle an event in which the Focus is lost by the StackPanel. In other words, when the focus is given to any other control that is not within the StackPanel.

The issue is that if I handle the LostFocus event of the StackPanel, this event is triggered even when the focus swaps between the TextBoxes that are within it (I guess this is due to the concept of RoutedEvent).

I tried also to handle the IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged event. It works for the TextBoxes, but then if the user clicks for instance in the TextBlock, the keyboard focus is lost and thus the event is triggered.

Please note that adding a name to the TextBoxes and filtering it in the LostFocus event is not an option, as these elements would be inside a ListView thus I can't add names to the TextBoxes.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You may try to handle the LostFocus of the children and set the RoutedEventArgs.Handled property to true to prevent the event from bubbling up to the StackPanel:

```
void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   e.Handled = true;
}
```